# Upload Image Byte Array File to server jersey from android?

Tags: java, android, arrays, file-upload, jersey

I'm working on an image comparison project where I download an Image from a URL and comparing it to an image stored previously on my android mobile device. 
First I registered the user with image as byte array and send the image to server for download later.

There is no problem in download section. I manually copied the byte array image file from mobile to server folder, and later download the same file, it is matching with existing image. But the problem is uploading part, the file uploaded into server folder but it is not matching with existing one.
I thing the file content is not uploaded properly, but i am not sure.

Please share any source for upload byte array image from android to jersey.

I have shared my upload code here for your consideration.

```
try {
            // open a URL connection to the Servlet
            FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(sourceFile);
            URL url = new URL(upLoadThumprintUri);

            // Open a HTTP  connection to  the URL
            conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            conn.setDoInput(true); // Allow Inputs
            conn.setDoOutput(true); // Allow Outputs
            conn.setUseCaches(false); // Don't use a Cached Copy
            conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
            conn.setRequestProperty("Connection", "Keep-Alive");
           // conn.setRequestProperty("ENCTYPE", "multipart/form-data");
            conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data;boundary=" + boundary);
            conn.setRequestProperty("uploaded_file", fileName);

            dos = new DataOutputStream(conn.getOutputStream());

            dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + lineEnd);
            dos.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"uploaded_file\";filename=\""
                    + name + "\"" + lineEnd);

            dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);

            // create a buffer of  maximum size
            bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();

            bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
            buffer = new byte[bufferSize];

            // read file and write it into form...
            bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);

            while (bytesRead > 0) {

                dos.write(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
                bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
                bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
                bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);

            }

            // send multipart form data necesssary after file data...
            dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);
            dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + twoHyphens + lineEnd);

            // Responses from the server (code and message)
            serverResponseCode = conn.getResponseCode();
            //String serverResponseMessage = conn.getResponseMessage();

            //Log.i("uploadFile", "HTTP Response is : "                        + serverResponseMessage + ": " + serverResponseCode);


            if (serverResponseCode == 200) {

                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                    public void run()
                    {
                        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                            public void run() {
                                String msg = "File Upload Completed.\n\n See uploaded file here : \n\n" + " serverpath"
                                        + uploadFileName;
                                mTxtMessage.setText(msg);

                            }
                        });                          
                    }
                });
            }

            //close the streams //
            fileInputStream.close();
            dos.flush();
            dos.close();

        } catch (MalformedURLException ex) {

            //dialog.dismiss();
            ex.printStackTrace();

            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    mTxtMessage.setText("MalformedURLException Exception : check script url.");                        
                }
            });                
        } catch (Exception e) {                

            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    Log.e("Upload file to server", "Got exception=====: ");                        
                }
            });                
        }
```

My Server code:

```
@POST
@Path("/TEMPLATE")
@Consumes(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)
public Response uploadTemplateFile(@FormDataParam("uploaded_file") InputStream is,
        @FormDataParam("uploaded_file") FormDataContentDisposition formData) throws IOException
{       
    String fileLocation=formData.getFileName();
    String location="C:/Applications/Images";

    System.out.println("file name=="+fileLocation);
    BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));

    String line="";
    ArrayList list = new ArrayList();       

    try {
        while((line=br.readLine())!=null)
        {
            System.out.println(line);
            list.add(line);
        }
    } catch (IOException e1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
    System.out.println(list);   

    String a[]=new String[list.size()];
    System.out.println(list.size() +"::"+ a.length);    

    File dir = new File(location);              
    if (!dir.exists()) {
        dir.mkdirs();
    }

    File txtFile = new File(dir, fileLocation);     

    FileWriter fw=null;
    try {
        fw = new FileWriter(txtFile,true);
        for(int i=0;i<a.length;i++)
        {
            a[i] = list.get(i).toString();
            fw.append(a[i]);
            fw.append("\r\n");
        }
        //fw.write(line);

    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    finally
    {
        try {
            fw.flush();
            fw.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }       
    return Response.status(Status.OK).entity(line).build();             
}
```

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: `image as byte array`. There are so many image types. How can we know what is in your byte array if you do not tell? Tell it in your post.

Comment: `Thanks in Advance`. That would be a reason not to help you.

Comment: Thanks for your reply @greenapps. do you want to know the byte array content?

Comment: @greenapps: Actually i have written the fingerprint details, unique key value, and username into the file as byte.For your reference i shared my file write code in the next comment.

Comment: try{ f = new File( szFileName );
fs = new FileOutputStream( f );
CharsetEncoder utf8Encoder = Charset.forName( "UTF-8" ).newEncoder();
byte[] Data = null;
ByteBuffer bBuffer = utf8Encoder.encode( CharBuffer.wrap( m_UserName.toCharArray() ) );
Data = new byte[ bBuffer.limit()];
bBuffer.get( Data );
fs.write( ((Data.length >>> 8) & 0xFF) );
fs.write( (Data.length & 0xFF) );
fs.write(Data);
fs.write( m_Key );
fs.write( ((m_Template.length >>> 8) & 0xFF) );
fs.write( (m_Template.length & 0xFF) );
fs.write( m_Template );
fs.close();

Comment: `That would be a reason not to help you.`. And it is.

Comment: Thanx @greenapps. I solved the issue.